# PHP: If/Else Statement: Conditional Terms

Tags: php, if-statement

I have a script - where a user can view data from a text file, choose a line number, and then that line number (and corresponding text from the text file) will appear on another page.

The script from the 2nd page, copied below, works. But I want to add in an if/else statement (or something else is ok), which states something like:
IF the line number exists (and it can be accessed/displayed) - here it is. 
ELSE, that number doesn't exist try again. 
    //webpage 1
    
    Show:

```
//webpage 2 showtest.php
<?php
$searchfor = $_GET['keyword2'];

$lines = file('users.txt');
$l_count = count($lines);
for($x = 0; $x< $l_count; $x++)
{
}

echo $lines[$searchfor];
?>
```

WHAT I AM AIMING FOR

```
$lines = file('users.txt');
$l_count = count($lines);
for($x = 0; $x< $l_count; $x++)
{
}
if(....................){

echo "Match found:<br />";
echo $lines[$searchfor];}

else{(...................)
echo "This is not a valid term";
}
```

Comment: define "and it can be accessed/displayed"

Comment: In short, you'd output an html form, each line getting a unique identifier attached to it, so when the user clicks a button next to the line, you'd know which line needs to be displayed, etc...

Comment: @MarcB isn't the line number itself already unique for the file?

Comment: @RepWhoringPeeHaa: pretty much.

Comment: Re: IF the line number exists (and it can be accessed/displayed). I mean, if the number exists in the text file, there are no limitations to accessing the file, and no limitations to displaying the line on the webpage

Comment: @KGreen again: define "and it can be accessed/displayed"

Comment: I also already have the HTML form, and that works. Just need help with the If/Else statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if(array_key_exists($searchedfor,$lines)){...}else{...}`

Should work for you

Answer (score 1):

Using the `file` function stores everything in an array and you could therefore just search through the array using the `in_array` function.  By adding the `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES`  a newline at the end of each array element.  Experiment with adding this.

```
<?php
$file = file('users.txt',FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
if(in_array('string',$file))
{
   echo 'string exists';
}
?>
```

Comment: thanks for the tip on FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES - have added that in.